# Cycle shipping over cells after deletion

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a project and i am at the last step, what i want the last piece of code to do is delete all rows that do not start with 25, 26 or 27

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
        If Left(CStr(cell.Value), 2) <> 25 And Left(CStr(cell.Value), 2) <> 26 And Left(CStr(cell.Value), 2) <> 27  Then
            matchRow = cell.Row
            Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlDown
```

The results are not as hoped: some cells still remain after running it.
Ii think that with this method, when I delete a cell it shifts the cycle and it skips the next cell over.

How can i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

For deleting rows, it is good to start at the bottom and work up

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim counter1 As Long

lastrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, 
searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For counter1 = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    Select Case Left(CStr(Cells(counter1, 1).Value), 2)
        Case 25, 26, 27
            Cells(counter1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End Select
Next counter1
```

Comment: Just some “add-ons”: 1) “Cells(counter1, 1).EntireRow.Delete” could be simplified to “Rows(counter1).Delete” 2) “Case 25, 26, 27” could be simplified to “Case 25 To 27”

Comment: Note: `Cells.Find(what:="*", ...)` will return `Nothing` and make the chained `.Rows` member call blow up (error 91) if used on an empty sheet. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1188513) for a bullet-proof solution. Also, iterating cells like this is *slow*, and inefficient regardless of whether `Application.EnableEvents` is enabled (although disabling application events can make it complete faster) - there are better ways.

Comment: Not just "good" to start at the bottom and work up, it's the only reliable way (if you're looping through the rows...)